# Disable Mozilla Firefox to store javascripts

Tags: javascript, security, firefox, browser-cache

right now if you open view page source in Mozilla, 
you'll see an external javascript link.
if you click on that link the browser will show javascript function from browser cache.
but if you select view>>reload the browser will requesting to server.

on IE and Chrome you click the hyperlink from view source, it will always requesting to server.
is there a way to get a same behavior on Mozilla?

**EDIT**

I am a webmaster, and I wonder this will be done using javascript or anything server side code.

Comment: what's happened when you add `?random_number` at the end of the link?

Comment: How about using network.http.use-cache = false .You can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289751/turn-off-caching-for-javascript-files-on-firefox

Comment: is it possible to write in server side code?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say if you are **a webmaster** and want to disable caching of your scripts, or you are **a web surfer** and want to disable caching of script of websites that you visit.

### If you are a webmaster

If you are a webmaster then you can achieve it using correct `Cache-Control` and `Expires` HTTP headers, eg. by setting `Cache-Control` to `max-age=0` and `Expires` the current time. (See my answer to [Determining a page is outdated on github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556593/determining-a-page-is-outdated-on-github-pages/13106972#13106972) for more info on how to control the caching of websites.)

Keep in mind that it will put more load on your servers and make your website load longer for your visitors and [Loading Time Affects Your Bottom Line](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/loading-time/).

### If you are a web surfer

If you are a visitor and want to forse the reload of cached resources then you can use [many Firefox add-ons that let you control the caching](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/search/?q=cache) of websites, for example:
[Clear Cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/clearcache/), 
[CacheToggle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cachetoggle/),
[Empty Cache Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/empty-cache-button/) and many more.