# Github: Unable to sync pages directory

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am currently using Github pages to host my personal website. This evening when I was working on the project, I at some point tried to push my changes, but got an email from Github saying:

The page build failed with the following error:
unable to sync pages directory

I also checked the hosted page and sure enough none of the changes had been pushed. I am extremely perplexed as to why this is happening. Most of my changes were being made to my stylesheet, though I did delete a folder which it may not have liked. Before today the GH Pages had been performing wonderfully. I desperately need to make changes to this site so if anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Try sending Github an email. They fixed my problem manually within a few hours

Answer (score 6):

So I sent Github an email explaining the problem and it turns out it was a problem on their end. Good to know!

Comment: I had exactly the same experience right now, seems this is an ongoing issue over the years...

Answer (score 2):

I think you moved your `index.html` file to some location other than the root directory. If that is the case, then github will throw the error above. To resolve this, move your `index.html` file back to the root folder, and make changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and contacted GitHub support. This was their response:

> Thanks for reaching out, and sorry about that! It looks like you hit a temporary glitch with our system (you did nothing wrong). I've just triggered a manual Pages build and it succeeded.

Their workaround implies that if you don't want to contact support, you can just wait until your next commit or [manually trigger a build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24098792/145173).