# Github Pages serves `README.md` though it builds from `\docs`

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Even though Github Pages is configured to build off the master branch and serve `index.html` from the `/docs` directory, it's still serving the `README.md` file from the root directory. Here are my configurations, in case I'm somehow mistaken:

[Current Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFHFU.png)

And here's the repo: https://github.com/mattyoungberg/RGBTrainer

Here's what it currently serves: https://mattyoungberg.github.io/RGBTrainer (The `README.md` file in `\(root)`, not `\docs`)

Here's what I'd expect it to serve: https://mattyoungberg.github.io/RGBTrainer/docs/

This setup worked just fine two days ago on a feature branch. I merged it to master, changed the branch Github Pages pointed at to master, but now it's not behaving as I'd expect.

Can anyone tell me why this wouldn't work? **I've looked at all the other StackOverflow questions I can find, but they all seem to have a different angle to the question which renders them unhelpful in my situation.**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reverting the commit in an attempt to try the answer from [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc), it looks like a simple rebuild from Github Page's deployment process got it rendering correctly.

[This answer about whether or not you can force Github Pages to build without a commit is useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098792/how-to-force-github-pages-build)

In short, you can't. But you can push an empty commit. In this case, the revert also caused it to build this time and render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing, try and add an `index.md` or `README.md` in your `docs/` folder, to see if that file is picked up by the GitHub Pages generator.

`index.md` was mentioned in the [2016 announcement of that `docs/` feature](https://github.blog/2016-08-22-publish-your-project-documentation-with-github-pages/).
And I see a `readme.md` in [`jekyll/jekyll/master/docs`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/tree/master/docs).

Comment: The conversion from .html to .md has caused Github Pages to add some elements to the page, such as a header and then a couple of links that interact awkwardly with the main body of my page.