# Refreshing My Visitor's Cache

Tags: javascript, web, github

Pretty new, and not sure how to phrase this. But when anyone accesses my website (basically a testing ground for crimes against JS, CSS, and HTML) the page stays the same even if they come back after I've updated it. This goes for design and files (.pdf, .py). I was wondering if there was a way to get a computer accessing my site to see the changes I've made? I've researched a bit and I couldn't find anything, because phrasing the question was difficult. Additionally, I'm on a x.github.io web page. Is there something special I should so in github or is it the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining a page is outdated on github pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556593/determining-a-page-is-outdated-on-github-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload the client browser ignoring the cache: `window.location.reload(true)`