# Github gh-pages dosen't show update from laptop Browser

Tags: github, github-pages

I'v pushed a new version of code to gh-pages for 5 hours but the page doesn't show the update when i use the Chrome on laptop. however when I check the page from Safari of my cellphone, it just show the updated Page.
what could possibly be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a cache issue ([GitHub page should set aggressive cache header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12556593/6309))

Try and [reload the page on Chrome without cache](https://superuser.com/a/89811/141).
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>)
(On Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

Comment: that is exact the problem thanks you. strange thing is that I pushed last night several times and such a problem didn't occur.