# HTML5 - controlling cache expiration date

Tags: html, caching

I finally managed to get HTML5 cache work, but I can't find any solution how to control how long cache given elements. Google Page Speed is showing that cached elements should have expiration date.

I would be grateful if you could provide any tips  concerning that issue.

Comment: Would http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#offline be of any help ?

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#offline

> 5.7.7 Expiring application caches
>
> As a general rule, user agents should not expire application caches,
>   except on request from the user, or after having been left unused for
>   an extended period of time.
>
> Application caches and cookies have similar implications with respect
>   to privacy (e.g. if the site can identify the user when providing the
>   cache, it can store data in the cache that can be used for cookie
>   resurrection). Implementors are therefore encouraged to expose
>   application caches in a manner related to HTTP cookies, allowing
>   caches to be expunged together with cookies and other origin-specific
>   data.
>
> For example, a user agent could have a "delete site-specific data"
>   feature that clears all cookies, application caches, local storage,
>   databases, etc, from an origin all at once.

About the **Google Page Speed** warning, it is most likely to be on the **SERVER-side.**

You should take a look at your server config files, or perhaps your .htaccess files.

Related : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html5+cache+control

and from : [HTML 5 Cache Manifest Vs. Etags, Expires or cache-control header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956455/html-5-cache-manifest-vs-etags-expires-or-cache-control-header)

> Here are some resources that will get you started:
>
> - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/  A    Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache
> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache
>     Using    the application cache
> - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5  Cache manifest    in HTML5
> - http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/  Offline Web    Applications
> - http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html
>     Offline    Web applications