# Add Expires headers for Cloudflare (Google, Disqus)

Tags: cloudflare, disqus

I am using DNS management cloudflare.

My site get hosting services on jekyll and github

When I analyze my site at Gtmetrix, I encounter the error **"Add Expires headers"**.

*How can I fix this error?*

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KX5WC3P
https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=partner
https://ahmet123.disqus.com/
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
https://www.google.com/cse/static/style/look/v2/default.css
https://cse.google.com/adsense/search/async-ads.js
https://www.google.com/uds/css/v2/clear.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first and second answers here: [Github pages, HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798589/github-pages-http-headers)

You can't change the HTTP headers, but you can do something like:

`<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="600" />`

inside the `<head>` section of the layout you use for your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Hello How Fixing This problem after GT METRIX Performance Score

Add Expires headers

There are 9 static components without a far-future expiration date.

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-195633608-1
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CRoboto%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic&display=auto&ver=5.9.2
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-69EDJ9C5J7
https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js
https://harhalakis.net/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-69EDJ9C5J7&l=dataLayer&cx=c
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-W3NQ5KW
https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/linkid.js
```

Thank you.

Konstantinos Harhalakis