# Cache static pages and content nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a static content to cache using nodejs, as far I know there are two ways:

1. This can be done using nodejs:

   **app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: oneDay }));**
2. Add **x.appcahe** file with static contents to cache, then add manifest attribute in html tag:

   **`<html manifest="x.appcache">`**

So my question is what is the diffrence between both ways?

Comment: I've never heard of `x.appcache`, and neither has Google really.  Where did you see that you can use that in your HTML?  Your first method sets the appropriate headers for all types of content and is what you should be using.

Comment: @Brad https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Comment: @Brad http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the links!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the first, the node.js server is setting the [Cache-Control header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) using express.js functionality.
2. In the second, the HTML specifies a manifest to be cached by the browser.

If you search for "cache-control vs html manifest" you'll find a TON of details that exceed what can be written by me in a single answer.  However, this other question titled [HTML 5 Cache Manifest Vs. Etags, Expires or cache-control header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956455/html-5-cache-manifest-vs-etags-expires-or-cache-control-header) has a great summary and to quote

> The main differences between the HTML5 cache manifest vs. the
>   traditional HTTP headers:
>
> - for the cache manifest you need support in the browser
> - for the HTTP headers you also need support in the browser of course but it's more universal
> - you have more control over the caching with cache manifest
> - your website or Web app can work correctly offline with no connection at all
> - you can have two version of every resource - for offline and online usage
>
> The last point is very handy and lets you easily swap parts of your
>   website that need connection with eg. placeholders containing optional
>   comments that the user doesn't get full functionality without the
>   connection or whatever you want.

There are also some compatibility issues because some browsers don't always play according to the standards...so that's also worth researching and determining which (cache-control vs manifests) is best for your situation.