# Using php code in css file to create dynamic css dosen't works each time.. sometimes dynamic css not loaded only static rules in that css are loaded

Tags: php, jquery, css, .htaccess

I am trying to create a dynamic css. I am appending a variable in each rule of CSS. I have already tried to get that variable using cookie,session and get method but it works like 1 out of 10 times.

CSS file (component.min.css) :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8');
header('Cache-control: must-revalidate');
$appVar = "";

if(!empty($_COOKIE["_adl_appVar"]))
{
    $appVar = $_COOKIE['_adl_appVar'];  
}
elseif(!empty($_SESSION['_adl_appVar']))
{
    $appVar = $_SESSION['_adl_appVar']; 
}
 ?>

/* General styles for the modal */

/* 
Styles for the html/body for special modal where we want 3d effects
Note that we need a container wrapping all content on the page for the 
perspective effects (not including the modals and the overlay).
*/
.<?php echo $appVar ?>abs<?php echo $appVar ?>-perspective,
.<?php echo $appVar ?>abs<?php echo $appVar ?>-perspective body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.<?php echo $appVar ?>abs<?php echo $appVar ?>-perspective body  {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -moz-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
}
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "^.*?component.min.*?$">
SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```

Let's say for above case output will be this css

Rendered CSS (incorrect)

```
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

While if it should be rendered something like :-

```
/* General styles for the modal */

/* 
Styles for the html/body for special modal where we want 3d effects
Note that we need a container wrapping all content on the page for the 
perspective effects (not including the modals and the overlay).
*/
.9d94584f3c1af62a2078da0ec45702baabs9d94584f3c1af62a2078da0ec45702ba-perspective,
.9d94584f3c1af62a2078da0ec45702baabs9d94584f3c1af62a2078da0ec45702ba-perspective body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.9d94584f3c1af62a2078da0ec45702baabs9d94584f3c1af62a2078da0ec45702ba-perspective body  {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -moz-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I am loading css file using jquery (Please see below) :-

```
$("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css/component.min.css" id="component-css" type="text/css" media= "screen" />');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474345/force-browser-to-refresh-css-javascript-etc

Comment: To verify that this is not indeed a cache issue try doing a curl or wget (or equivalent) from command line to see what is returned.

Comment: Why do you need such a weird class name to be dynamically generated in the first place? I think it might be a rather bad idea to output this in (partially) dynamically created CSS resources; putting it into a `<style>` element directly inside the HTML code, or even using inline styles, might be the better option here.

Comment: @CBroe .. that is the problem here that I have only one option to load css that too using jquery only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what mistake I was doing.

Actually the problem was not with the php side or .htaccess side. The problem was with the dynamic css classes I was generating, when I was generating random classes sometimes it generated classes starting with digit and css doesn't support that.

Thank You