# Css file is not being updated after clearing cache

Tags: css

I did the following:
1. clearing cache (press Ctrl + F5).
2. remove css file and then upload again. 
3. checked updated css file manually.
4. I remove browser data from chrome setting

From the above test it should load updated css. but it is being loaded old css. 
Here is the old link: http://demo.voberhat.com/wp-content/themes/bootstraplight/style.css?ver=4.9.6

I can see update at : http://demo.voberhat.com/wp-content/themes/bootstraplight/style.css

Meaning version change may be the trick. But why should I change version just to add one line css? Any idea?

Comment: Do you have server side cache???

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css?version=51">

Answer (score 0):

[Force browser to refresh css, javascript, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474345/force-browser-to-refresh-css-javascript-etc)

Try this Stackoverflow thread. If it's not what your looking for then I can provide some PHP.