# HTML onclick="" doesn't work with radio button

Tags: javascript, html, input, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I'm making a flask website with bootstrap styling and I have a form with some radio style buttons (made with `<input>` html tag). I've been trying to call a js function through `onclick=""` but for me it only seems to work with real buttons (`<button>` tags). Here's my code.

```
<label id="multiBot" class="bsstyle" data-toggle="collapse" href=".multi-collapse">
   <input type="checkbox" name="multis" checked autocomplete="off" id="mult" value="Mults" onchange="canvititol()"> Text
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found that I can make it work just by changing `onclick=""` for `onchange=""`.

Comment: Also it may have to do with refreshing the cached data (Cmd+Shift+R in mac), which apparently is also a thing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474345/force-browser-to-refresh-css-javascript-etc). For me onclick doesn't work either, but onchange sometimes gets stuck and this solves it.