# Problem with "clear browsing data" in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am deploying a web from python using Flask and modifying javascripts. The problem is that every time I modify something in javascript I have to clear the browsing dadta in order to see the changes. I guess the old code remains in the cookies or something. It is really anoying to have to clear the browsing data all the time, how could I solve the problem?

I tried to work with incognito session but same thing happens.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do a hard refresh - ctrl f5 - it forces the browser to download all your files again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force browser to refresh css, javascript, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474345/force-browser-to-refresh-css-javascript-etc)