# style.css not working but style_copy.css is working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have been building a website for over a month now, nearly completed. All of a sudden, when I make a change to my style.css file, the change does not appear when I refresh the page in the browser.

The strange thing is that, if I make a copy of the file, called style_copy.css, and link to that and make changes, then the changes do appear in the browser.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this is occurring?

I am browsing on Google Chrome (94.0.4606.61) and editing in Visual Studio Code (1.61.0)

Thanks

Comment: Browsers cache stylesheets, did you try using a hard-refresh? `ctrl-f5` or `ctrl-shift-r`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force browser to refresh CSS, JavaScript, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474345/force-browser-to-refresh-css-javascript-etc)

Comment: So you're saying that this only happens in Chrome? Not Firefox or Edge?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the css file has been saved.

If the file is already saved, then the issue is most likely because your browser has cached (saved an old version of) the file.

Then, try restarting the browser to clear the cache.

Also, try waiting and reloading, the file will likely update by itself pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of restarting the browser, you could also hit CTRL + F5