# How to force visitor browser to delete cache

Tags: asp.net, browser-cache

How can you force user browser to delete its cache that belongs to your website.
Is this possible? For example a redirect problem occurs. Later it get fixed. But stupid browser caches redirect due to error and keep doing it.

This is fixed when the cache deleted. Is this possible via asp.net?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force browser to clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`

Read more about [Useful HTML Meta Tags](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html)

[How to prevent caching in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067)

Comment: It won't  help if its a redirect

Comment: if you write this, would browser cache any redirection ?

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about HTTP301 then you can't do anything about it:

http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/

You can add another redirection though, so if A is redirecting to B and it should redirect to C than change B to redirect to C.

Answer (score 0):

huMpty duMpty answer is correct. You cannot force a client to empty its cache as that is a client side file system command.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force browsers to clear their cache, you can only give hits of what can be cached.

The only way to avoid your problem is versioning url's and changing the version after the fix. The problem is that you should have done it in advance, and it's not always worth it / practical.