# how do I reset the browser cache when reloading a page

Tags: html, browser-cache, page-refresh

I have a page that I'm changing however, the changes can only be seen when I reset my browser cache. Is there something I could add to my html which would do this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's to view css or js changes one way is to append _versionNo to the css/js file for each release. E.g.

script_1.0.css script_1.1.css script_1.2.css etc.

You can check out this [link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479551) to see how it could work.

Source: [Force browser to clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with plain HTML with "meta" tags.
Meta tags belong to the "header" tag and are used for many different things, including to prevent cache and expiring the content de-facto.

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" /> <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

These are 2 good tags for that. Good browsers should recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I sometimes use is to add a parameter to the linked file. So, if it's the stylesheet you want to update, use something like screen.css?version=123. You can then update it to 124, and the browser will forget it's cached version and fetch it again. Be careful not to update too often on a live site - you'll ruin your user's lives if they have to download your core resources every time they visit.

Doing it this way means you'll only have to work on one named version of your file. Which keeps it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the resource that you need to reload. There are many different methods you could use, one common one is to use versioning or timestamping the request. So when you get the files that need to bypass the cache you request them using a timestamp for example like so (Exaple using C# + Razer).

```
<script src="/Js/Functions.js?t=@DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to actually clear a browser's cache from a page or its resoruces. There are ways around this, however.

One way is to append a "version number" to your resource files. This tricks the browser into thinking the resource is a different file, and will download it again. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache) has some answers that can help you do that. The query string method is probably the easiest to control and maintain, if you use server-side code like PHP/JSP/ASP.NET to generate a unique version number to put into the query string. Note that you would have to build it to not happen in production, otherwise your users will be forced to reload resources with every page request, which will increase load times for them.

Another alternative, since you are developing, is to use some developer tools on your browser to disable your cache:

- Chrome Developer Tools has native support for this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)'s accepted answer for how to disable the cache in Chrome. Note that you have to have your developer tools open in Chrome for cache disabling to work.
- Firefox has several ways to do this, as enumerated in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/23134/how-to-turn-off-the-firefox-cache) on SuperUser.
- Internet Explorer's developer tools support this as well, as is evident in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/461285/how-to-disable-caching-in-internet-explorer-9) on SuperUser. You may have to keep the developer tools open for this to stay in effect.

If you use a different (or a variety of) browser for development/testing, you should be able to Google how to disable the cache on that respective browser.

Firefox and Chrome also support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for cache-less page reloads.

Comment: Instead of a version number, you can just use the file last-modified time.  Append that as a querystring parameter!

Comment: @Doin A last modified date is a type of version numbering, it's just based on dates rather than arbitrary numbers attached to potentially arbitrary change steps. I put it in `"` on purpose to indicate that it can be any kind of number/value that one can change when desired.

Comment: Ok.  It's just that "version number" probably doesn't suggest "last modified date" to most people who might read this, and "last modified date" is a particularly simple solution, because you don't have to keep track of anything.  So I thought I should mention it.