# Load images directly from server

Tags: html, css, caching, web, proxy

I have a web page of which most of the assets have changed recently. But when I load the page for the first time, it shows the old images, yet if I refresh the page, it loads the new ones.

So please tell me how to load the new images directly from the server when I open the page for the first time.

I suspect this has something to do with caching?

Comment: When opening the page for the VERY first time, the images will be fetched from the server. If you have already visited the website before, and the images were cached, only a refresh action will work to see the old images. This is because you told the browsers to cache the images in the first place...

Comment: What you are asking about is Browser Caching- you can use ctrl-f5 to force a reload, but knowing that is the name of your problem, perhaps you could find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache

Comment: the images are cached. press Ctrl + F5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include a query string after the image name, and increment the value each release, this will make the browser download the new asset.

E.g.

`http://www.example.com/image1.jpg?v=1` - on first release
`http://www.example.com/image1.jpg?v=2` - on the next release

This also works for stylesheets, JS and other external resources.

Comment: you could set it a variable that is stored in a global config file `$version = 'X'` and append this to the asset.

Comment: @PatrickGeyer yes if there are too many images. But my project i sprited the image into big one.So that`s not that problem too me.

Comment: @MungunbatEnkhbayar what server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpg)$">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Put that in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Works only for HTML files, not images

Comment: @Reeno Oh, ok. Couldn't one somehow put something like this into the server configuration file?

Comment: Stackoverflow eats my line breaks... Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/sCdE1MCg

Comment: Yes, your new edit should work. But I think (I'm not sure) it only works if you apply it from the beginning. Now that the files are already cached it might be the wrong way to force a refresh.

Comment: Removing caching altogether would slow client-side load times on subsequent reloads. Unless the project has a requirement for zero caching, it's preferable to refresh the cache when an asset is changed.

Comment: @Oli true, that definitely is a valid point if you're dealing with a content-rich site. Else I doubt the difference in loading would make a noticeable difference.

Comment: It makes a huge difference, even with only a few already compressed images on a site...

Comment: OK, you're probably right. I don't have much experience with web servers :)

Comment: Your code prevents any caching from the beginning. Mungunbat Enkhbayar was asking how to bypass caching if it's already active.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I'll leave the answer up in case anyone else finds it useful.