# Deployed polymer webapp caching pages

Tags: heroku, gruntjs, yeoman, polymer

I have a Polymer webapp initially scaffolded using Yeoman and then deployed to Heroku with the simple following *web.coffe* script:

```
gzippo = require 'gzippo'
express = require 'express'
morgan = require 'morgan'

app = express()
app.use morgan('dev')
app.use gzippo.staticGzip "#{__dirname}/dist"
app.listen process.env.PORT || 5000
```

The problem I am facing is that (at least in Chrome and Safari) every time I deploy a new version I have to clear the browser cache and data to see the changes. Refreshing the page multiple times does not work. However with my local *grunt server* changes happen as expected in the browser UI.

Where can I start inspecting this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3):

A workaround, same concept that use in this thread:

[Force browser to clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache)

is just add a "version control" in your elements on the link import

```
<link rel="import" href="elements/my-element.html?v=0.02">
```

It's quite tedius :(

Answer (score 2):

Another kind of Cache that can happen is the service worker cache and had me struggling for a while.
This one if you are on Chrome you need to delete it in dev tools resources tab, there you will see Service Workers on the bottom. Just delete everything (trash on top right).

This is not really related to the question but can help fellow Googlers that may pass by.