# Changed css isn't showing up on installed forum package

Tags: php, css

I installed [My Little Forum](http://mylittleforum.net/documentation/installation) on my website. I changed the style.min.css file to give it a different look. When I download that file from the server and open it, it has the changes I made. But the forum displays the same as before.

The instructions say that is the file to change. The forum is [here](http://moonwards.com/forum/). What should I do here?

This is the code that has changed, from the minified file:

```
body{color:#ccc;background:#333;margin:0;padding:0;font-       family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:100.01%;}
a{color: rgba(255, 200, 0, 1);text-decoration:none;}
a:visited{color:rgba(255, 150, 0, 1);}
a:hover, a:active {color: rgba(255,255,60,1); background-color: rgba(50, 50, 0, 1);}
a.stronglink{padding-left:13px;color:rgba(255,255,60,1);text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;background:url(images/bg_sprite_1.png) no-repeat 0 4px;}
a.stronglink:visited{color:rgba(255, 150, 0, 1);}
a.stronglink:hover{color:rgba(255,255,60,1);text-decoration:underline;background:url(images/bg_sprite_1.png) no-repeat 0 -46px;}
a.stronglink:active{color:rgba(255,255,60,1);}
#top{margin:0;padding:0;height:4.4em;color:#000;background:#d2ddea url(images/bbnav2.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
```

Comment: It may be to do with [browser caching](https://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens).

Comment: I added the code. Since nothing had changed i supposed it wasn't relevant, but i guess it is.

Comment: @jaunt - that hasn't been an issue as i develop the rest of the site. But indeed you are right, i reloaded it and it shows up. Does it take more time to  propagate because it has a database and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is to do with browser caching. From time to time you may have to forcibly tell your computer to request for the information from the website server again. As explained [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens)...

> ...the browser stores the information on your computer so it reloads it
> from your computer, not from the actual site...
>
> ...the problem comes when you make a small change to your site and the browser doesn't recognize it as a significant change, so it reloads the same page you just looked at. The solution is to clear or empty your browser's cache...

It has nothing to do with your website, it's purely all local work. There are some cheeky ways to force your users to update their chache. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1922924/4907552) is a good way of doing so.

Comment: @JoaquínO Links to other StackOverflow answers are permalinks: they cannot, and will not, stagnate. The answer will not be deleted as it has received too much recognition. I have quoted the relevant texts from the other link.