# Hot to make visitors of my page automatically see the updated version (prevent caching)

Tags: caching, html

I have a webpage I update pretty often. No big things, but sometimes a text, sometimes an image.

Because of local caching it happens a lot that my visitor see an old version of the webpage.

Is there a way I could force the visitors' devices to not load the old cached version if their last call was before a specific timestamp? I'm tired of telling them to hit F5 to get the earliest version.

Comment: I suggest reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache If you want a more modern way of doing it with HTML5, I recommend reading the answer by user **rsp**