# How to force a complete page reload (not refresh) in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a `DropDownList` that lets the user change the themed stylesheet for a website.  It does an autopostback to save the selection to my database.  After this saves I want to force a complete page reload (not refresh).  So the link to the stylesheet is rebuilt and the form is reset.  Is this possible?

I have tried both:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

And even tried JavaScript:

```
window.location.reload();
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
```

but these just seem to cause a refresh.  I seek a way that acts as if I clicked in the address bar and pressed `[Enter]`.

**UPDATE**
This was a common case of not thinking things through thoroughly.  I was attempting to do these actions through an `iframe` but the parent page was actually the one that set the theme stylesheet.  I ended up getting this accomplished by simply:

```
If IsPostBack() Then
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
    sb.Append("window.top.location.reload();")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "reload", sb.ToString())
End If
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Add appropriate tags to your question.

Comment: @roryap `vb.net` is not an appropriate tag for a `vb.net` question?

Comment: Sure, but you seem to be having trouble with some web technology sub-set?  ASP.NET possibly?  You have sufficient rep to know how this works by now...I came here because I though it was a general vb.net question, and I don't know much about ASP.NET, so I was annoyed.  That's what the purpose of tags are; if I had seen the appropriate tags, I would have just ignored the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to do something like cache bursting with version number, which is suggested in: [Force browser to clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache)

Comment: I'll give this a quick try.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do as you are doing .... but also avoiding cache, adding this meta to your web page:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

And an old date

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Sat, 31 Oct 2014 00:00:00 GMT">
```