# Clear cache? in c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I have a web app running, but sometimes it fails when trying to go to another page, i think it might not even get to submit the changes in the db.

When the user saves the changes, it shows the typical "the webpage is not available", like the picture below:

[image: Error from Google Chrome]

The thing is that if i run the same URL, it works to me, but in the computer with the problem, i need to clear the cache before it allows me to go to the next page. I tried to check the connection, pinging the server, and in 25 packages i sent, only one crashed for timeout. 
Since the only solution i've found to fix the problem is to clear the cache, i want to know if there is a way to do it by code. I am programming in c#, MVC4.
Another weird thing is that before i published some changes in the page, there is no problem in the other version, and i didn't make any important changes (that involved the core of the code).

Is there any other way to fix this problem?.

Thanks!

Comment: Clear _what_ cache?

Comment: The cache of Google Chrome. I use an extension of Chrome called "Clear Cache", that allows me to clear the app cache, cache, form data and local storage.

Comment: Does saving involve uploads such as a file or content?

Comment: Just saving in the database. But it happens in different parts of the application. If i refresh the page, it stills shows me the same error until i clear the cache of Chrome

Comment: have you tried in different browser?

Comment: Yes, i tried with Internet Explorer, and it works fine for a while, until it crashes for the same reason. But yet again, if i clear the cache, it works fine again (for another while).

Comment: can you check if your <httpRuntime     maxRequestLength="" > in your web.config?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127572/discussion-between-krishnadhungana-and-ignacio-sanhueza).

Answer (score 1):

In your mvc controller you can add

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult functionName(){ ... }
```

you can add on a method in your controller or in all controller

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class SolicitudController
```

you can read about that in https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

You can also try using javascript in your html
[Force browser to clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache)

I hope I help you!

Comment: I'm going to try this in my next publishing and tell you how it went. Thanks!