# Force browser to clear cache in Angular environment

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, cache-invalidation

There is a popular question on how to force-clear the cache of the browser in a VanillaJS application, with the general consensus being, setting the name of the .js-script or the scripts arguments to a new value: [Force browser to clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache)

How can I achieve this with Angular (currently 5.1 in AngularCLI/Webpack build), so every time I release the code in production (with AOT), a new version is built? I would use date-hashing instead of indexing, but the main question is: where can I set it (eg the script name/arguments)? In development, where the CLI takes care of rebuilding the app, this is not an issue, just in production!

Comment: This is i did for angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment/61473275#61473275c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By setting your build command to target production `ng build --target=production`, the cli automatically hashes your js files. Here are the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds) You can also set the command manually if you wanted it on dev `ng build --output-hashing=all`

Comment: Thank you. I have made the changes, but need to check if it works first, will accept your answer after that :)

Comment: But how do I enforce the browser to also refresh asset files when a new version is created?

Comment: @CularBytes It looks like angular cli doesn't hash all assets (see this [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4212)). You might be able to update the webpack config to look for your asset urls and add a hash or make a pipe that adds a hash. (for example say you had a pipe that pulled in your package.json version and appended it to the url. everytime you update the version and deploy the asset would be cache busted)