# css file not showing changes after making changes in scss file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I just converted scss file into css file using npm as per the instructions on this 
[link to instructions](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc) and it worked fine for the first time and scss file compiled with a css file autogenerated but now when I make changes to scss file , I don't see css file to change on its own and I have to use **npm run watch-css** every time and then run the server .Is there any way to do this such that I don't have to run server again and again?

I am adding the package.json file .

```
{
  "name": "mydecisionapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "loader": "^2.1.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.1.11",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "style": "^0.0.3",
    "validator": "8.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: May be a caching issue.  Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache

Comment: I need to run npm run watch-css everytime .

Comment: why not add it to your `npm start`?

Answer (score 0):

In the instructions you have posted you will find the answer if you keep following the "Adding a CSS Preprocessor" section.

Install **npm-run-all** and modify your scripts section as follows

```
"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
"start-js": "react-scripts start",
"start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
"build-js": "react-scripts build",
"build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

This simply runs the two scripts in parallel, meaning that **npm start** will now both handle the watching of your scss files, and run the server