# Expire file which has already been cached with max-age

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, caching, http-headers

Is there a way to expire a file on a user's device which has already been cached using `Cache-Control max-age=LARGE_NUMBER`.

I want to force the users to download the latest file but the file has previously been cached for a long duration and users will continue to see the old version for far too long. I now know that I need to set `cache-control` to `no-store` and I have done this but this doesn't help for the users who have already got the cached version.

I have also set `Expires` to 0 but as stated here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires, `cache-control` takes precedence over `expires` so that doesn't solve my problem.

For info, this is occurring on the `index.html` file of my react application.

I've seen this - [Force browser to clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache) and nothing helps. I've tried adding a query string to the html file but this results in a 404.