# How to circumvent browser caching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, web-deployment

On a react site I noticed that every time I upload a new version the user has to refresh 1-2 times until that new version is shown. Is there a way I can force Chrome (or whatever browser) to remove the saved version of my site?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1922910/4051471)?

Comment: are you using service-workers?