# How to clear cache on a static asset

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, caching

I have a web component that is embedded into a page using a file called `loader.js`. I do not have control of the filename as it's being called in a separate application. How would I **always** reload that file whenever the page is loaded, so that the file is never delivered from HTTP cache? Normally, I would add some sort of suffix to the file based on the build such as `loader.js?v123.4`, but in this case I don't have access to the code that is calling it since it's embedded in another application. How could I do this?

Comment: What's your goal? You can do this with dev tools if you need this for dev purposes. This is solved from server side, as you may notice from other cache-related questions. You can't do anything from client side if it's not your app (except maybe patching XHR which is not a proper option by any means).

Comment: This will help you to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018813/5233738

Comment: @VaibhavBhuva where? That is saying exactly what I'm saying in my question I'm not allowed to do. We don't have control of the application that is embedding it.