# My CSS file won't update on Safari Browser

Tags: css, browser, safari

I have tried refreshing and clearing the cache but it still shows the same old file with no changes. Meanwhile every other browser will show the change made in the css file. I changed the name of the css file and upload it and Safari notices the change and applies it. I don't want to have to change a name file every time. Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reason stated. It's a rant and not a programming question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force browser to clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache)

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the end of the file

```
style.css?v=1 or style.css?v=1.1
```

works for me

or `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $filename;?>?v=<?php echo $fileModified ; ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

I am solving this issue by appending Last Modified Date of the CSS file as a query parameter, like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/wannacat/style.css?ver=1631280487" />
```

With PHP, you can get it like this:

```php
$version = filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css');
```

When the file is updated, Safari (as well as all other browsers) will recognize that they need to fetch the latest version of the file.