# Completely getting rid of a Progressive Web App

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I have no idea how PWA Apps work. I have good front-end and Javascript knowledge, however. I have a client, whose current site is a PWA made using Workbox. Now I have to redesign that site for the client.

When I go live with the new site, all new visitors get the new site design. But old visitors, who had already visited the site in past, are still seeing the old site.

I don't have access to the PWA site code either. All I have is the domain access, using which I can point the domain to the new server with the new design.

Can any PWA or Workbox expert out there help me with this scenario? Any kill switch or workaround to force old users' browser to point to the new server?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like this problem could be solved by deleting the cache of the old users.
In that case, it could be solved like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1922924/11403867) by Fermin, by adding a version number either to, or after the file names. Like this:

```
script_1.0.css // This is the URL for release 1.0
script_1.1.css // This is the URL for release 1.1
script_1.2.css // etc.
```

or this:

```
script.css?v=1.0 // This is the URL for release 1.0
script.css?v=1.1 // This is the URL for release 1.1
script.css?v=1.2 // etc.
```

Comment: As the question says, I don't have access to the PWA code.