# Browser Clear Cache for Tailwind CSS Production

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-mix, alpine.js

Everytime I release a new page for my laravel application, some tailwind classes didn't work. I need to clear cache from the browser first, then those classes works. It applies to everyone that already saw the earlier page and look at the new one.

**Does tailwind css have any solution to solve this problem?**
Because not everyone who visit my page knows if the problem is the cache.

Comment: See if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache

Comment: Take a look at Laravel Vite.