# Internet explorer does not send "If-Modified-Since" header

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, http-headers, last-modified, if-modified-since

I'm trying to use HTTP "If-Modified-Since" header.

1. My server responds to every HTTP request with "Last-Modified" header.
2. When the client sends the same request again, it updates the "If-Modified-Since" header 
   accordingly.

This works fine with Chrome and Firefox but not with Internet-Explorer 11.

I tried adding "Expires" header and set it for '-1', As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917586/http-cache-check-with-the-server-always-sending-if-modified-since). However it didn't work either.

These are the respond header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Pragma: 
Cache-Control: Public
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 02:00:00 IST
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Tue, 29 Jul 2014 07:54:08 GMT
Etag: 2014-07-28 18:57:23.0_2108737535
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Jul 2014 18:57:23 IDT
Cache-Control: max-age=10
Content-disposition: inline; filename=Ad.pdf; filename*=UTF-8''Ad.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 27743
```

Any suggestions?

TNX